# reset a form to the default values

Tags: javascript, jquery, default-value

Currently I have:

```
$("#your_email").val(this.defaultValue;)
```

I want to be cycling through all form elements and resetting them to their default value

Comment: Do you have to use jQuery? Why not just use an input of type reset? It's meant to do exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Esteban: [because jQuery is the answer to everything](http://www.doxdesk.com/updates/2009.html#u20091116-jquery).

Comment: Doesn't seem to me that a jQuery solution was requested. `this.defaultValue` implies a native solution.

Comment: @BalusC - Tru dat. Seems SO isn't so much a technology q/a platform as a soapbox for jQuery evangelists.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

you don't need jQuery for this, just get the form dom element and call reset() on it.

Or, fetch with jQuery like:

```
$("#myFormId")[0].reset();
```

Comment: cheers, thought there would be something obvious, don't know why I missed it.